# How to use Tonelli`s theorem

Tags: measure-theory

I have some difficulty in dealing with the absolute value under the integral. Let $X=Y=[0,1], \mu=\lambda=$ the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1].$ Let $0=\delta_1<\delta_2<\delta_3..., \delta_n \rightarrow 1.$ Let $f_n$ be real continuous functions with support in $(\delta_n, \delta_{n+1}),$ such that $\int_0^1 g_n(t)\,dt=1, n=1,2,3...$

Let $f(x,y)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} [g_n(x)-g_{n+1}(x)]g_n(y).$

I need to show that: $$ \int_0^1 dx\,\, (\int_0^1 |f(x,y)|\,dy) = \infty.$$

It is clear that for each point $(x,y),$ at most one term of the sum is non-zero, unless $x,y$ belong to different intervals $(\delta_n, \delta_{n+1})$.
I have troubles to see if $g_n$ can take negative values.

To compute the integral in parethesis one can fix $x$. If $x\in (\delta_n, \delta_{n+1}),$ then this integral is non-zero if $y\in (\delta_n, \delta_{n+1}).$ Thus: $$\int_0^1 |f(x,y)|\,dy=\int_{\delta_n}^{\delta_{n+1}} |f(x,y)|\,dy.$$

Unfortnately I cant go further. So I need some support or a solution proposal. Many thanks.

Comment: What is $f_n$? A typo and it should be $g_n$ instead?

Comment: Do it indirectly. **If** the integral were finite, Tonelli's theorem would assert something. Check whether the assertion holds.

Comment: Thanks. This is the point. I dont know how to use Tonelli´s theorem, which enables the use of Fubini´s theorem. If the integral were finite, then it will mean that the function $f$ is integrable, and if this were the case then I could use Fubini´s Theorem of iterated integrals. Maybe finding an upper bound of the function which is itself integrable or proving to the contrary that each upper bound of the function is not integrable can help out. I have a problem with absolute values under the integral ! Can you give me a suggestion ?

Answer (score 2):

Just notice

$$\int_0^1 \left(\int_0^1 |f(x,y)|\,dy\right)dx = \sum_{n}\int_{\delta_n}^{\delta_{n+1}}  \left(\int_0^1 |f(x,y)|\,dy\right)dx.$$

If $x\in (\delta_n, \delta_{n+1})$ then $f(x,y) = g_n(x)g_n(y)$ and $|f(x,y)| = |g_n(x)||g_n(y)|$. Therefore
$$\int_{\delta_n}^{\delta_{n+1}}  \left(\int_0^1 |f(x,y)|\,dy\right)dx = \int_{\delta_n}^{\delta_{n+1}} |g_n(x)| \left(\int_0^1 |g_n(y)|\,dy\right)dx.$$

Since $$1 = \left|\int_0^1 g_n(y)\,dy\right| \leq \int_0^1 |g_n(y)|dy$$
we have $\int_0^1 |g_n(y)|dy \geq 1$ and then 
$$ \int_{\delta_n}^{\delta_{n+1}} |g_n(x)| \left(\int_0^1 |g_n(y)|\,dy\right)dx \geq \int_{\delta_n}^{\delta_{n+1}}|g_n(x)|dx = \int_0^1 |g_n(x)|dx \geq 1.$$

So, we have

$$\int_0^1 \left(\int_0^1 |f(x,y)|\,dy\right)dx = \sum_{n}\int_{\delta_n}^{\delta_{n+1}}  \left(\int_0^1 |f(x,y)|\,dy\right)dx \geq \sum_n 1 = \infty.$$